# How to rebase quarterly price index?

Tags: macroeconomics, price-index, data, base-year

For rebasing annual price index, we divide all price indices by the value of the new base year.

With quarterly price indices, there is not a single base year with the value 1.00. In the base year, there are 4 quarters and none of their values is 1.00. I calculated the average of 4 quarters, it is still not 1.00, something around 0.87.

How can one rebase the quarterly price index to another quarterly base year?